# Couldn't match type 'a' with 'Integer'

Tags: haskell

I am working on cis194 spring15 homework04, on this line:

https://github.com/cmal/cis194-15/blob/master/src/HW04.hs#L113

What I am trying to implement is the `fromInteger` function for `Num` instance on a `Poly a` type, where `Poly` means polynomiol whose type constructer is `P`.

I tried

```
instance Num a => Num (Poly a) where
    (+) = plus
    (*) = times
    negate      = times (P [-1])
    fromInteger n = P [n] -- this line
    -- No meaningful definitions exist
    abs    = undefined
    signum = undefined
```

, but I got the following error:

```
  Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Integer’   
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by the instance declaration at HW04.hs:109:10-30  
  Expected type: Poly a  
     Actual type: Poly Integer   
  In the expression: P [n]    
  In an equation for ‘fromInteger’: fromInteger n = P [n]
  In the instance declaration for ‘Num (Poly a)’ 
  Relevant bindings include 
     fromInteger :: Integer -> Poly a
```

How to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Please copy and paste the relevant code directly here

Comment: You probably want `fromInteger n = P [fromInteger n]`

Comment: @shree.pat18 sorry, I will do that right now.

Comment: @leftaroundabout amazing! but why?

Comment: Use `InstanceSigs` and write out the explicit type of `fromInteger :: Integer -> Poly a`. This shows that the argument of `fromInteger n` has type `n :: Integer`. But the argument to `Poly` is a list of generic numbers `[a]`s. You need to call `fromInteger n :: a` to translate it from an `Integer` to a number. This is exactly what the error message is saying, it expected `Poly a` but got a polyomial of a concrete type `Poly Integer`.

Comment: If "No meaningful definitions exist" of `abs` and `signum`, should `Poly a` really be an instance of `Num`? It's not true that there is no meaningful definition of `abs(ax^2+bx+c)`; that's a reasonable thing to ask for, and it has an answer. What you mean is that there is no meaningful definition of `abs` whose type matches `Poly a -> Poly a`, because the absolute value of a polynomial _is not itself a polynomial_. The same is true of `signum`. This is a glaring red flag that the instance you are trying to define is not internally consistent.